# placing text labels on top of boxplots ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to place the labels on top of the boxplot.

```
xx = data.frame(group = c(1), year = as.character(c(2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018)), value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0))
xxLabs = xx %>% 
  group_by(year, group) %>%
  summarise(lab = median(value))

ggplot(xx, mapping = aes(y = value, color = year, x= group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(aes(y = lab, label = lab, x = group), data = xxLabs)
```

What do I have to change so that the labels fall on top of their respective instead of being placed down the middle?

Answer (score 1):

You could take this as a starting point

```
xx = data.frame(group = c(1), year = as.character(c(2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018)), value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0))
xxLabs = xx %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(lab_text = median(value), lab_pos = quantile(value,0.9))

ggplot(xx, mapping = aes(x = year, y = value, color = year)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(aes(y = lab_pos, label = lab_text), data = xxLabs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(xx, mapping = aes(y = value, color = year, x= group)) +
  geom_boxplot(position=position_dodge(width=0.8)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = lab, label = lab), data = xxLabs, position=position_dodge(width=0.8))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.