# ggplot2 - categorical boxplot with complex summary annotation

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, boxplot, summary

I'm trying to plot a categorical boxplot in R using `tidyverse` & `ggplot2`, with `x` = categorical column, `y` = continuous column, and additional information at the top of each value of `x`.

In each value for `x`, there are a number of outliers that are below a certain fixed threshold value `V`. The required calculation I have for this is something like:

```
df %>%
  select(x, y) %>%
  group_by(x) %>% summarise(n_per_grp = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(below_thresh = if_else(y < V, 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(below_thresh == 1) %>%
  group_by(x, n_per_grp) %>%
  summarise(n_below_thresh = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(perc_below_thresh = round(n_below_thresh/n_per_grp*100, 3)) %>%
  mutate(final_lbl = paste0(perc_below_thresh, "% (", n_below_thresh, "/", n_per_grp, ")")
```

I'm aware of `stat_summary(fun.data = myfunc)` to plot metrics like `mean()`, `median()`, `length()`, etc. However, I cannot figure out how to use `geom_boxplot()` & `stat_summary()` to annotate each boxplot with `final_lbl`. I'm not sure whether `stat_summary()` is even the right thing to use.

Any help in understading this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my own question, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60605783/placing-text-labels-on-top-of-boxplots-ggplot2). I was questioning whether I really needed `stat_summary()` for what I was trying to do, and had the idea to "calculate" my per-group annotation label outside the main plot code.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
n_categ = 10
n_ppl = 1000

df = tibble(col_x = rep(LETTERS[1:n_categ], n_ppl)) %>% 
  arrange(col_x) %>% 
  mutate(col_ppl = rep(ids::uuid(n = n_ppl), n_categ)) %>% 
  arrange(col_x, col_ppl) %>% 
  mutate(
    col_y_1 = rbeta(n = n_categ*n_ppl, shape1 = 60, shape2 = 120),
    col_y_2 = rnorm(n = n_categ*n_ppl, mean = 100, sd = 25),
    col_y_3 = runif(n = n_categ*n_ppl, min = -100, max = 100),
    col_y_4 = rbinom(n = n_categ*n_ppl, size = 1, prob = 0.5),
    ) %>% 
  mutate(col_y = (col_y_1 * col_y_2) + (col_y_3 * col_y_4)) %>% 
  mutate(col_y = if_else(col_y < 0, 0, col_y)) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("col_y_"))

df_annot = df %>% 
  mutate(ypos = round(max(col_y) * 1.05, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(col_x, ypos) %>% mutate(n_per_grp = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(below_15 = if_else(col_y < 15, 1, 0)) %>% 
  filter(below_15 == 1) %>% 
  group_by(col_x, ypos) %>% mutate(n_below_15 = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(perc_below_15 = n_below_15/n_per_grp*100) %>% 
  group_by(col_x, ypos) %>% 
  summarise(final_lbl = max(paste0(perc_below_15, "% (", n_below_15, "/", n_per_grp, ")")))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = col_x, y = col_y)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 15, linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_text(aes(y = ypos, label = final_lbl), data = df_annot, hjust = 0) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 15, 50, 100, 150, 200), minor_breaks = FALSE) +
    xlab("Category") + ylab("Measure") +
    expand_limits(y = c(0, 200)) + coord_flip()
```

This gives me the plot I was looking for:

[Resulting boxplot with categorical labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88nQl.png)

Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I think the most helpful way of understanding this is with an example.
Your data should look like the following data frame.

```
df <- tibble(category = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                       500),
             value = rnorm(500*4))

> df
# A tibble: 2,000 × 2
   cat      value
   <chr>    <dbl>
 1 A      1.26   
 2 B     -0.326  
 3 C      1.33   
 4 D      1.27   
 5 A      0.415  
 6 B     -1.54   
 7 C     -0.929  
 8 D     -0.295  
 9 A     -0.00577
10 B      2.40   
# ℹ 1,990 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

You can use the following code to plot this data frame in a boxplot.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = category, 
             y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(aes(label=round(..y..,2)),
               fun.y = mean, 
               geom="text",
               vjust = -0.5)
```

[Then you should get something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ASNZ.png)

Based on this, you can add other layers showing the median or anything else.